# Can't see Ubuntu partitions in Windows disk manager!

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

Apologies for any stupid questions as I am an Ubuntu newbie (an impressed one, for sure!).

I have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 using wubi. Before doing so, I however did not create a separate partition on my hard drive. My hard drive has a single partition i.e., C: which had a Windows 7 installation and I installed Ubuntu in the same partition. I have a few questions around this:

1. First of all, can there be any issues with the way I have installed Ubuntu i.e., in the same partition as Windows? If so, what are they? Is it recommended that I move the Ubuntu installation into another separate partition? If not, the rest of my questions are kind of irrelevant, but it might still be helpful to get the answers for the same for my understanding.
2. How safe is it to create a new partition from Windows disk manager without adversely affecting my system including my Ubuntu installation? I would think it should be safe, but I have scorched my hands earlier with partitions and don't want to jump into it without expert advice.
3. From what I have read on the forums, it looks like directly moving the Ubuntu installation to the newly created partition is not going to be possible. Am I right?
4. If I have to uninstall Ubuntu and re-install it again into the new partition (I am ok to do this for at the moment, I have not had the Ubuntu installation even for a month and there is no data I have created in it and not many programs installed yet), I understand that I have to use a program like EasyBCD to overwrite the boot record from Windows and then delete the Ubuntu partitions from Windows disk manager. Before I do that, I wanted to check if I could see the Ubuntu partitions from Windows disk manager, but I can't. How will I be able to delete them then or uninstall Ubuntu?!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When installing using wubi the filesystem is just a file in your windows C: drive. You can use some tools to mount this in windows. Wubi is only meant to test Ubuntu and isn't good as a long term solution. So your best bet is to back up any user data onto a USB and remove wubi from add and remove programs in windows. This will unintall ubuntu. Then download the ubuntu .iso image, and write it to a usb or dvd, and use that to install properly to a separate partition. Don't try and do any partitioning yourself, the installer can manage it for you if you select install alongside windows 7.

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful and in one shot, answers all my questions.

Comment: @Apps Please mark it as the answer if it solved your question.